# set_autocommit got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_begin_transaction_with_broken_autocommit'

Tags: django

I've just upgraded to Django 1.9, and I'm getting this error, which seems to exist entirely inside the django stack, when I run tests.

```
File "~/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 482, in setup_databases
    self.parallel, **kwargs
File "~/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 726, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
File "~/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 70, in create_test_db
    run_syncdb=True,
File "~/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 119, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)     
File "~/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options
File "~/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 89, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
File "~/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
File "~/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
File "~/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 176, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
File "~/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
File "~/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in ensure_schema
    with self.connection.schema_editor() as editor:
File "~/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 84, in __enter__
    self.atomic.__enter__()
File "~/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 184, in __enter__
    connection.set_autocommit(False, force_begin_transaction_with_broken_autocommit=True)
TypeError: set_autocommit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_begin_transaction_with_broken_autocommit'
```

Answer (score 14):

Ah ha! This is the error you get if you upgrade to Django 1.9 while using django-transaction-hooks and leave the transaction-hooks engine set up in settings.

Comment: This way Fix to me.